# react-leaflet map does not show up

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

i have this code in one of my components

```
class MyMap extends Component {

   state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 11
    };

    render() {
        const position = [this.state.lat,this.state.lng]
         return (
             <MapContainer  className="mymap" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}  scrollWheelZoom={false}>
             <TileLayer
                   attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>  contributors'
                   url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              />
              <Marker position={position}>
              </Marker>
            </MapContainer >
      )
  }
}
```

Also i have install leaflet by this command

```
  npm install -s react-leaflet
```

Also i have insert the leaflet's CSS in my index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
crossorigin=""/>
```

Also i give in MapContainer a

```
ClassName="mymap"
```

Which includes the following CSS code

```
 .mymap {
     height: '100vh';
     width: 100%;
}
```

So my problem is  that my map is not show up, can anyone help me?

Comment: This could be related to different things... any errors in the console? are you importing the Map component, etc at the top of your component file?

Comment: I am importing them like this: import { MapContainer , TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

Comment: try to add a min-height of 600px on your .mymapp class

Comment: i getting an error in console that says: http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css can't load because the type MIME text/html is not file text/css. I don't use bootstrap in this component

Comment: google maps work fine for the same thing that i wanto to accomplished, but i don't know if they are free to use it, i mean don't show up the tag (only for develepers). So this is why i use leaflet. Should i use google maps eventuallly?

Comment: Leaflet should work, you might not be setting it up properly

Comment: there is another step besides the ones I mentioned above??

Answer (score 6):

import leaflet.css

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
```

then set inline style for `<MapContainer>`

```
<MapContainer style={{ height: "450px", width: "100%" }} center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
```

Comment: Worked for me. For a full height map I'm using `height: 100vh`. Using `100%` does not display any tile

Comment: not showing any marker

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. I have to get rid of this from my index.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq /sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
  crossorigin=""/>
```

Also in my MyMap component i inserted this

```
 import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

Comment: Glad you could fix it, that's a better approach to include css files!